# "smelling of fish" and "fishy"; "it smells of" and "it smells like"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Can we convert a noun into an adjective by putting "**of**" before that noun?

People say "**[she is a woman of great determination](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/of)**", so I think "**of determination**" plays a role of an adjective and modifies "**woman**".

**Can we do the same for other nouns?**

We have "**fishy**" meaning "**smelling of fish**".

But how to express the smells of "cake/candy/pee" when we have no equivalent adjectives.

Is it idiomatic "**it smells of cake/candy/pee**"?

Are they idiomatic and the same "**it smells of cake/candy/pee**" and "**it smells like cake/candy/pee**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the noun into a preposition phrase doesn't convert it into an adjective, but the phrase can act as an adjective, as in your example, "of great determination" more or less equals "very determined".

In "it smells of pee." there is no adjective. Rather the phrase is another way of saying "It has a/the smell of pee." where "pee" is a noun. For an adjective, you might say "It has a urinous smell.", but you'll be understood quicker with "It smells like pee."

Similarly, you could say "cake-like" or "candy-like" smell, but it would be unusual, and not as understandable as "smells like...".

It would also be very strange to say "It smells of cake/candy." Neither of the two has a unique characteristic, pervasive smell, in the way that urine does. If I heard "It smells of cake!", I would think someone was joking.

Comment: Something can smell _pissy_, at least in Britain (men's public toilets did, often, when I was younger).

Comment: I wondered about the word "pissy", but the only dictionary definitions I found were those that meant "surly", more or less.

Comment: Meaning of pissy in English: pissy ADJECTIVE 1 vulgar slang Relating to or suggestive of urine --Lexico (Oxford)

Comment: OK; I see Wiktionary shows that meaning too.

Answer (score -1):

It smells of cake - there is some cake involved here.

It smells like cake - no cake anywhere in sight, but something different that for some reason smells the same.

“Fishy” and “this smells fishy” has a totally different meaning that has nothing to do with fish: It usually means “dodgy” or “suspicious”.